# Editable PostGIS materialized view

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Is it possible to create an editable materialized view in PostGIS?
The idea is as follows: when changing the values in the materialized view, the values in the table on the basis of which the materialized view was created are changed. A materialized view is created on a piece of data in one table.

Editable views aren't fast enough

Comment: PostGIS doesn't have views, though PostgreSQL does. This seems more like an issue for [dba.se].

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html `... the materialized view cannot subsequently be directly updated...`. The flow goes in opposite way: you can update the main tables then refresh the materialized view. That does not resolve the issue with the speed. Try to find what is the bottle neck and optimize the database accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialized views in PostGIS are not updateable. See https://postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html

> Materialized views in PostgreSQL use the rule system like views do,
> but persist the results in a table-like form. The main differences
> between:
>
> ```
> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mymatview AS SELECT * FROM mytab;
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE mymatview AS SELECT * FROM mytab;
> ```
>
> are that the materialized view cannot subsequently be directly updated
> and that the query used to create the materialized view is stored in
> exactly the same way that a view's query is stored, so that fresh data
> can be generated for the materialized view with:
>
> ```
>  REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mymatview;
> ```

Thus, the data flow goes in opposite way: you can only update the main tables and then refresh the materialized view. That does not resolve the issue with the speed. Try to find what is the bottle neck and optimize  database accordingly.